# Arithmetic Progression - Find sum

Tags: arithmetic

i been stuck with this question. Thanks for helping in advance.

Question:Suppose you are training to run an 8km race. You plan to start your training by running 2km a week, and then you plan to add a ½km more every week. At what week will you be running 8km?

Ps: I need to use arithmetic sequence to show the working for these. Im also confused as to what equation to use in these since decimals are used. Working's would be appreciated alot.

Edit: I solved it :D

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Week $1$ : $2$ km.

Week $2$ : $2.5$ km.

Week $3$ : $3$ km.

Week $4$ : $3.5$ km.

Week $5$ : $4$ km.

Week $6$ : $4.5$ km.

Week $7$ : $5$ km.

Week $8$ : $5.5$ km.

Week $9$ : $6$ km.

Week $10$ : $6.5$ km.

Week $11$ : $7$ km.

Week $12$ : $7.5$ km.

Week $13$ : $8$ km.

Comment: i already figured it using this way as well, but i want to substitute this into a arithmetic sequence formula. But im unclear on substituting with decimals.

Comment: The general formula for an arithmetic sequence is $u_n = u_1 + (n-1)d$ when $u_0$ is the first term and $d$ the common difference. Here $u_1 = 2$ (number of kilometers at week $1$), and the common difference is $0.5$. So the formula that gives you the number of kilometers at week $n$ is $2+0.5(n-1)$. Now you just have to find $n$ such that $2+0.5(n-1) = 8$.

Comment: I still dont get how to find n? Can i know what this formulas name is or so? I think i should find more similar decimal questions to understand this...

Comment: Do you know how to find $n$ from the equation $2 + 0.5(n-1) = 8$ ?...

Comment: Uh is it like these? 
0.5 (n-1)+2=8
0.5n-0.5+2=8

Comment: $2+0.5(n-1)=8$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $0.5(n-1) = 6$ $ \Leftrightarrow$ $n-1 = 12$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $n=13$. If you have difficulties to solve these kinds of equations, I would advice you to forget about arithmetic sequences and try to learn some basic maths first...